How do I make IIS Express run in HTTP1.1 mode in .NET Core?
With Kestrel I can do the following:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http1"
    }
  }
}

to make it run in HTTP1.1 mode.
How can I achieve the same with IIS Express? At the moment it is defaulting to HTTP2

IIS 10 version 1089 and above supports the new binding flags to suppress HTTP/2, https://learn.microsoft.com/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/bindings/binding You might try to see if the IIS Express version you installed actually supports the same. And if not, you need to switch to full IIS 10.

If you just want to test with http 1.1 with asp.net core application, there is no need to set the IIS express setting.
Inside the asp.net core to use the http 2, it must use the https and the tls version should be TLS 1.2 or later connection.
So you just need to set the asp.net core launch settings and program.cs to disable the https redirect.
More details, you could refer to below codes:
1.Modify the program.cs to disable https redirect.
...
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
//remove the https redirection
//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
...

Use the http to access the web site.

Result:


Yeah I was able to work this one out - however I want HTTP/1.1 with SSL :(

I tested with the bind settings with  sslFlags="4" inside the applicationhost.config with the binding and it failed. Other way you could try is disable the tls version above the tls 1.2 by changing the register inside your computer.
